# Can't create a directory in node

Tags: chef-infra

I have write the simple recipe here which is to create a directory in the node. But it shows error while  running the chef-client.

directory "~/build" do

action :create

end

```
* Parent directory ~ does not exist, cannot create ~/build
================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'directory[~/build]'
================================================================================

Chef::Exceptions::EnclosingDirectoryDoesNotExist
------------------------------------------------
Parent directory ~ does not exist, cannot create ~/build
```

thanks for your valuable comments.

Comment: Its becuase of ~ sign. I think you need to use .. instead of that

Comment: but normally can make directory with this command: mkdir ~/build Why not in chef?

Comment: Because `~` is a *shell* shortcut for $HOME. Ruby has no special meaning for `~` so replace it by `$HOME` and it will create the directory in the home of the user running chef (usually root).

Comment: again it shows the same error                                       * Parent directory $HOME does not exist, cannot create $HOME/build

Comment: bash "create directory" do
code <<-EOH
mkdir ~/build
EOH
end
   This recipe create the directory build. But using directory resource getting the above error..

Comment: Ooops, hit myself by the same, `$HOME` as no meaning in ruby, sorry. `directory "#{ENV['HOME']}/build"` would be better. (again it will be in the home dir if the user running chef.

Comment: You're welcome. I'll write it as an answer to avoid noise around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` or `$HOME` have no meaning in ruby, they're ok in shell context.

`directory "#{ENV['HOME']}/build"` would be better.

it will create  the directory in the home dir of the user running chef.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, ~ has no context in Ruby, but you can use File.expand_path to alter it to the correct directory...

```
directory File.expand_path("~/build") do
  action :create
end
```

This looks cleaner than the approach above, at least to me, but they are still correct.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/File.html#method-c-expand_path